# Facing cluster testing issue with ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have 2 instances of ActiveMQ Artemis , simply created with command 
**/.artemis create artemis/server1** and

**/.artemis create artemis/server2**

I am using linux ubantu.

here is **broker.xml for server1:**

```
  <acceptors>
     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

  </acceptors>

  <connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
     <!-- connector to the server1 -->
     <connector name="server1-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
  </connectors>

 <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
```

and here is **broker.xml for server2:**

```
     <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
   <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
  </acceptors>

  <connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
     <!-- connector to the server0 -->
     <connector name="server0-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
  </connectors>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>server0-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
```

Also in server2, change in bootstrap.xml, changes web bind port

```
<web bind="http://localhost:8163" path="web">
```

I am testing it with [StaticClusteredQueueExample](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery) and this example working file.

Now I am running the ActiveMQ Artemis JMeter Performance against my cluster, I am using JMeter Testing Examples which is [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/perf/jmeter)

Now when i am running [point to point test](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/perf/jmeter/1.jms_p2p_test.jmx) with Jmeter is giving me near 50% errors rate (Aggregate Report in Jmeter) in consumer,

But where i am running only one node(any of server1 or server2) in ubantu system, it's working fine, 0% error rate(Aggregate Report in Jmeter).

Can you please help why i am getting 50% errors rate(Aggregate Report in Jmeter)  when running multiple instances(nodes) with docker

Comment: Help really can't be given until it's clear what the errors actually are.  Also, a clearer explanation of the test would be helpful as well (e.g. Is JMeter being run in one of the Docker containers or somewhere else?).  Lastly, is the cluster actually forming properly?

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for your response, 
I have updated my question, also facing the same issue without docker so updated details is tested with local machine(in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing one example (i.e. the JMeter example) with a cluster configuration (i.e. from the clustered-static-discovery example) that really isn't compatible.

The [<message-load-balancing>](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html) of the cluster is STRICT which means messages will be load-balanced across the cluster regardless of the presence of consumers.  Furthermore, the default [<redistribution-delay>](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html#Message-Redistribution) is -1 meaning the messages sent to the other nodes in the cluster due to the STRICT message-load-balancing type will stay on those nodes and will not be redistributed based on consumer demand.

The JMeter example was written with a single node in mind so it only send messages to and consumes messages from 1 node which means it will only receive back half of the messages that it sends as the other half will have been forwarded to the other node in the cluster due to the configuration.

If you change the <message-load-balancing> to ON_DEMAND you won't see any errors as all the messages will stay on the node where they were specifically sent which is also where the consumer will be connected.

Comment: Hi @Justin, may be i am wrong,
In StaticClusteredQueueExample 
connection is created with only one server
```ConnectionFactory cf0 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61619");```
 but 4 consumer getting data from all 4 artemis servers  (using round robined). 
Now the Jmeter consumer is connection TCP://localhost:61616 servers, so why same things is not happening for the Jmeter consumer, why it's cluster not returning data for it...

Comment: The StaticClusteredQueueExample uses the *same* connection factory to create all the connections and this is why connections are load-balanced across the nodes in the cluster in a round-robin fashion.  However, JMeter will look-up the connection factory in JNDI for *every* thread which means the connections will not be load-balanced since there will just be 1 connection per connection factory.

Comment: Hi Justin,
but load balancing is in server side, 
If I am talking about tomcat load balancing, then if multiple requests come from multiple browsers, then load balancer handle every request  and distribute those all request(round-robin fashion) on multiple nodes and gives back response to browser,
but here half of the request of consumer are success and 50 % fails

Comment: Load balancing happens at 2 levels.  There's message load balancing which is done by the broker based on the <message-load-balancing>.  Then there is connection load balancing which is done by the client.  In the case of the JMeter example connection load balancing isn't happening as far as I can tell.  In other words, all the connections are being concentrated on a single node of the cluster.  However, at the same time message load balancing is happening as messages are being distributed between the nodes in round-robin fashion effectively starving half the consumers and causing errors.